# Why am I getting different resluts between oracle sql developer and fiddle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was working on a query. I have a table called bonuses, it has bonus_date(has the first day of the months) and bonus_duration(months). and I want to check if the current month has a bonus or not!
for example, bonus_date can be 1-DEC-21 and bonus_duration 2 then the months with bonuses are DEC-21 and JAN-22!
this is my query :

```sql
SELECT
    bonus_value
FROM
    bonuses
WHERE
        employee_id = 1
    AND trunc(sysdate, 'mm') BETWEEN bonus_date AND add_months(bonus_date,(bonus_duration - 1));
```

and it returns nothing for me!

[image: bug]

so I tried to send a fiddle to my friend to help me fix the problem but the fiddle gave me the results I'm looking for and I'm so confused I can't understand what's the problem!

[image]

fiddle: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19ae1f/1)

Comment: If you run the sample ddl directly on your actual database, and then run that select statement, do you get a result? If not, what is the result of running `select value from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';` in your database?

Comment: I expect that Brian is right. In your `insert` statements on **fiddle** you give strings as values for dates. That is a very bad (but common) habit of many programmers. A date column should be given values of `date` data type. If you give a string like `'01-DEC-21'` the database will use a default format model; in **fiddle** it is probably `'dd-MON-rr'` but in your real-life database it may be `'dd-MON-yyyy'`, and this will interpret 21 as the year 21 (in the times of the Romans), not 2021. Which would explain the discrepancy.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia oh actually I didn't think about trying that.
I was inserting data without INSERT statements so I didn't know it makes a difference.
I tried it and worked and understood what is the problem!
the result of running what you asked to run was (DD-MON-RR) so how can I fix the problem then?

Comment: Date literals are written like `date '2021-12-21'` (in that exact format, including the `date` keyword). See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1

Comment: An alternative to using the DATE literal, you could use the [to_date function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118).  Looks like a matter of personal choice as to which, but the key point is you need to (1) understand the difference between a DATE and a string representation of a DATE, and (2) be very explicit about converting the string to a DATE.